# Issue in calling Activity from the IntentService class

Tags: android

In my app, I am using the `IntentService` class to start another activity in the background. But the issue I got is that suppose from the `IntentService` class I start my activity, which opens my activity, after that I don't close my activity. Then I notice that when `IntentService` class again wants to start my same activity it is not called as the same activity is not close.

So, my question is: How can I start the same activity again and again whether it is open or close from the `IntentService` class?

**Code in IntentService class**

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService
{       

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public AlarmService() {
        super("MyAlarmService");
    }
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {          
        startActivity(new Intent(this, 
            AlarmDialogActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use launchMode tag in manifest file

```
  <activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"

        android:launchMode="singleTask"  />
```

it will not create a different instance of activity if already available..

see this link [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for better understanding

Comment: can u help me to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373130/how-to-get-foldername-and-filename-from-the-directorypath