# How to get FolderName and FileName from the DirectoryPath

Tags: java, file

I have DirectoryPath:
`data/data/in.com.jotSmart/app_custom/folderName/FileName`
which is stored as a String in `ArrayList`

Like

```
ArrayList<String> a;
a.add("data/data/in.com.jotSmart/app_custom/page01/Note01.png");
```

Now from this path I want to get `page01` as a separate string and `Note01` as a separate string and stored it into two string variables. I tried a lot, but I am not able to get the result. If anyone knows help me to solve this out.

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/filesanddirectories.html#SPLITTING I found that helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`f.getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29)

> Returns the pathname string of this abstract pathname's parent, or null if this pathname does not name a parent directory.

**For example**

```
    File f = new File("/home/jigar/Desktop/1.txt");

    System.out.println(f.getParent());// /home/jigar/Desktop
    System.out.println(f.getName());  //1.txt
```

**Update:** (based on update in question)

if `data/data/in.com.jotSmart/app_custom/page01/Note01.png` is valid representation of file in your file system then

```
for(String fileNameStr: filesList){
  File file = new File(fileNameStr);
  String dir = file.getParent().substring(file.getParent().lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);//page01
  String fileName = f.getName();
  if(fileName.indexOf(".")!=-1){
     fileName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually i edited my question..I have made some mistake regarding what i want.

Comment: Updated the answer to remove extension

Answer (score 1):

create a file with this path... 
then use these two methods to get directory name and file name.

```
file.getParent(); // dir name from starting till end like data/data....../page01
file.getName(); // file name like note01.png
```

if you need directory name as page01, you can get a substring of path u got from getparent.

Comment: But in my case its not a file its a string which i stored in an ArrayList like ArrayList<String> a; a.add("data/data/in.com.jotSmart/app_custom/page01/Note01.png"). Now i want page01 as seperate string and Note01.png as seperate string

Comment: I want to stored it into String variable like String s1 = page01 and String s2 = note01 from the path

Comment: the same i mentioned dear, You can store both these values in Strings,
and when i said create a file means,, u have to give path of the file, If file is already present there, the File file will have the reference of the same path.

Answer (score 1):

For folder name: `file.getParentFile().getName()`.

For file name: `file.getName()`.

Comment: This can be a good answer if you tell the OP how to get a file from a String and then supply a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `.split` ?

```
answer = str.split(delimiter);
```